# Python elasticsearch helpers.bulk erroneously fails? (script or doc is missing)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

With the following payload in a python function

```
[{'_id': '979507',                                                                                                                                            [15/1871]
  '_index': 'follow-search-alias',
  '_op_type': 'update',
  '_type': 'follow',
  'script': {'inline': 'ctx._source.followers += follower',
   'lang': 'groovy',
   'params': {'follower': ['3054805']}}},
 {'_id': '979507',
  '_index': 'follow-search-alias',
  '_op_type': 'update',
  '_type': 'follow',
  'script': {'inline': 'ctx._source.following += user_being_followed',
   'lang': 'groovy',
   'params': {'user_being_followed': []}}},
 {'_id': '3054805',
  '_index': 'follow-search-alias',
  '_op_type': 'update',
  '_type': 'follow',
  'script': {'inline': 'ctx._source.followers += follower',
   'lang': 'groovy',
   'params': {'follower': []}}},
 {'_id': '3054805',
  '_index': 'follow-search-alias',
  '_op_type': 'update',
  '_type': 'follow',
  'script': {'inline': 'ctx._source.following += user_being_followed',
   'lang': 'groovy',
   'params': {'user_being_followed': ['979507']}}}]
```

I get the following error with python's elasticsearch when I use helpers.bulk()

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'action_request_validation_exception', u'Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;2: script or doc is missing;3: script or doc is missing;4: script or doc is missing;')
```

Exactly how can this be?  Every single element in this array has a script tag.  The function itself has been working for many other cases, just not this one and a select few others.

Running it manually in the shell works, but not in this function?

Function is as follows:

```
@classmethod
def add_follows(cls, follows):
    docs = []
    user_ids = [f.follower_id for f in follows] + [f.followed_id for f in follows]
    users = User.query.filter(User.id.in_(user_ids)).all()
    valid_user_ids = set([u.id for u in users])

    grouped_follows = {}

    for follow in follows:
        if (follow.follower_id not in valid_user_ids) or (follow.followed_id not in valid_user_ids):
            continue
        if not follow.follower_id in grouped_follows:
            grouped_follows[follow.follower_id] =  {
                'followers': [],
                'following': []
                }
        if not follow.followed_id in grouped_follows:
            grouped_follows[follow.followed_id] =  {
                'followers': [],
                'following': []
                }

        grouped_follows[follow.follower_id]['following'].append(str(follow.followed_id))
        grouped_follows[follow.followed_id]['followers'].append(str(follow.follower_id))

    for user_id, data in grouped_follows.items():
        follower_action = {
            '_index': FSC.FOLLOW_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME,
            '_type': FSC.FOLLOW_SEARCH_MAPPING_NAME,
            '_id': str(user_id),
            '_op_type': 'update',
            'script': {
                'inline': 'ctx._source.followers += follower',
                'params': {
                    'follower': data['followers']
                    },
                'lang': 'groovy'
            }
        }

        followed_action = {
            '_index': FSC.FOLLOW_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME,
            '_type': FSC.FOLLOW_SEARCH_MAPPING_NAME,
            '_id': str(user_id),
            '_op_type': 'update',
            'script': {
                'inline': 'ctx._source.following += user_being_followed',
                'params': {
                    'user_being_followed': data['following']
                    },
                'lang': 'groovy'
            }
        }

        docs += [follower_action, followed_action]

    print docs
    if docs:
        helpers.bulk(es, docs, request_timeout=300)
```

I'm currently running this in a shell.  I even put two lines:

```
global payload
payload = docs
```

And in the shell run

```
# after the above function fails
In [96]: helpers.bulk(es, payload)
Out[96]: (4, [])
```

So it works?  Same payload?  Same function?  Just now it lives outside of the function?  I can't even be confident this library will work in production given these problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to debug without additional information, could you enable logging for `elasticsearch` logger and paste the output somewhere as it should contain the full information including the actual data sent to elasticsearch? Thanks